# Sequelize check constraint other column

Tags: javascript, constraints, sequelize.js

I have a model with two date fields (from and until). I would like to add a constraint to this model, checking whether these dates are on the same day. Is this possible using Sequelize? [The documentation only showcases the check constraint with constant values](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-addConstraint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `check` and `where` clause

```
"use strict";
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface
      .createTable("Users", {
        id: {
          allowNull: false,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        startDate: Sequelize.DATE,
        endDate: Sequelize.DATE,
      }).then((result) => {
        return queryInterface
          .addConstraint("Users", ['endDate'], {
            type: 'check',
            where: {
              endDate: {
                [Sequelize.Op.gt]: { [Sequelize.Op.col]: 'Users.startDate' }
              }
            }
          });
      });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("Users");
  }
};
```

If we try to insert the rows into db violating this constraint, we will get an error like below

[image]